# Hibernate configuration in libraries

Tags: java, hibernate

Lets say I have two applications which both use Hibernate and both share some functionality, if I were to separate the shared functionality into a library what is the best way to structure the hibernate configuration?

I don't want to have to replicate the shared parts of the hibernate configuration in both my applications so is there a way I can save some configuration in the library (i.e. just the mapping elements for classes in the library) which is then loaded dynamically into the applications hibernate config at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use spring, you could create an abstract bean with your base hibernate configuration, and then have your clients extend from that.

By using annotations, much of the mapping configuration ends up bound to the code. Library clients then only need to specify the package so that the hibernate annoatations are processed and added to the mapping configuration.

Comment: this means that if you want to use different configuration (such as connect to a different database host), you have to go back into the library (which should just be for functionality) and change the config for each different scenario for the client app. Doesn't seem reasonable

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put all thge mapping elements in a jar & reuse them you can use the tag

```
<mapping jar="" />
```

here you pass the path & the name of the jar file (so the jar could be reused over & over again).
with this technique you will be able to share the hbm configs only..

if you need to share any other components there are different ways to do that.